# Comments on site don't show on moderation page

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have Faceboook social comments embedded on my website: http://www.photodharma.net, but when I look at the Comment moderation tool only the comments on the front page show up, and I was not even informed about those.

Each of the pages has the following code embedded:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="myname"/ >
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my-id"/>
```

So my question is how can I set it so that all comments appear in the Comment moderation tool, and how can I be informed when someone makes a new comment?

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I think it may be broken. It doesn't work for me either. Perhaps its a caching issue??

Answer (score 2):

Normally the Comment Moderation tool does all that automatically for you. So, from what I can tell the CM-tool isn't able to connect to the comment boxes on your website.

These are the only two things I can think of:

1. There's no need for the fb:admins meta-tag since you can choose who moderates your comments using the CM-tool. Delete this meta-tag, it might cause conflicts.
2. In https://developers.facebook.com/ >> Apps >> Your Comment Appname
   Go to '+ edit app' and make sure that the 'App domain' field contains a url that does not include "http://www.", just your plain url-name.
   Make sure that under the 'website' tab at the bottom, your complete website-url is filled out, including the "http://www."

Curious to see if this was of any help. I understand your frustration though, the documentation of the fb:comments is seriously lacking imho.

Comment: Dear Pascalculator, many thanks for your comment. Since I wrote the question I have taken down the Facebook comments from the website: partly out of frustration, so I cannot now check the steps you suggest. I hope your answer, though, will be of help to others.

Comment: If you ever feel like giving it another try, I'm here to get you through it if you can't get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to make sure the correct app id is configured on the website. Facebook would look for

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR APP ID HERE" />
```

which will add the comments in the right place.